Is there a way to read a SQL worksheet on Snowpark?
I have a stored procedure that I want to run using a Python script on Snowpark. But I want to read the SQL from another worksheet. Is there a way to read such files on Snowpark
Workaround for this is to upload that file to stage and read that file, but I want to know if reading a SQL worksheet directly would be feasible

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
